# Future meaning: "I'm seeing" vs " I'll see"

Tags: future-tense, present-continuous

Could you please explain to me why they use the Simple Future "**I'll see**" in **Sentence 8**? (in the attached picture).

I answered **"I'm seeing**" because i thought that "*the meeting is set (tomorrow) and they have already planned it". And for arranged actions, we use Present continuous*"

Please help me clarify this case. Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Helen could tell Tina "I'm meeting Jenny at the cinema tomorrow night" because the meeting is already planned, but Jenny says "I'll see you tomorrow" as part of the conversation _making_ the plan.

Comment: Thank you, Kate. I got the idea. I've been learning English grammar and I find it difficult sometimes to do exercises even when I have read the rules.

Comment: Please show you effort first, such as a grammar tutorial.